# How do I use UI Automation on a WPF ItemsControl that groups items?

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, ui-automation

I am using [Microsoft UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) (i.e. [`AutomationElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)) to run automated acceptance tests against my application. This has gone well, but I've hit a situation that doesn't appear to be exposed to the automation framework.

I have an [`ItemsControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) (although I could be using one of its derived controls, e.g. [`ListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)) and I am using [`CollectionViewSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to group items. Here is a complete window to demonstrate:

```
<Window x:Class="GroupAutomation.Window1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="Orchestra">
    <Window.Resources>

        <!-- Take some simple data -->
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="SampleData" XPath="Orchestra/Instrument">
            <x:XData>
                <Orchestra xmlns="">
                    <Instrument Name="Flute" Category="Woodwind" />
                    <Instrument Name="Trombone" Category="Brass" />
                    <Instrument Name="French horn" Category="Brass" />
                </Orchestra>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>

        <!-- Add grouping -->
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleData}}" x:Key="GroupedView">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="@Category" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>

    <!-- Show it in an ItemsControl -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedView}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4">
        <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Padding="4" Margin="4" Background="#FFDEDEDE">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
                        <Button Content="Play" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

This produces a window containing the items grouped into their categories, and each item has a button that I'd like to click with UI Automation:

[image: Screenshot of window with a list]
<sub>(source: [brizzly.com](http://pics.brizzly.com/thumb_lg_2C45.jpg))</sub>

However, if I look in [UISpy.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms727247(v=vs.110)) (or navigate with `AutomationElement`) I only see the groups (even in the Raw view):

[image: UISpy]
<sub>(source: [brizzly.com](http://pics.brizzly.com/thumb_lg_2C47.jpg))</sub>

As you can see, the groups are there but they contain no items, so there is nowhere to look for the buttons. I have tried this in both WPF 3.5 SP1 and WPF 4.0 and get the same result.

Is it possible to use UI Automation on items that are grouped, and if so, how?

Comment: Use directly the itemscontrol items as shown here. [link](http://abusanad.net/2016/12/19/wpf-itemscontrol-with-teststack-white/)

Answer (score 9):

I came across this problem and managed to solve it by implementing a 'GenericAutomationPeer' from

- [Helping the Coded UI Framework Find Your Custom Controls](https://colinsalmcorner.com/genericautomationpeer-helping-the-coded-ui-framework-find-your-custom-controls/)

and adding a special case for `GroupItem`s.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Automation.Peers;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Xml;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class MyItemsControl : ItemsControl
    {
        protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
        {
            return new GenericAutomationPeer(this);
        }
    }

    public class GenericAutomationPeer : UIElementAutomationPeer
    {
        public GenericAutomationPeer(UIElement owner) : base(owner)
        {
        }
        
        protected override List<AutomationPeer> GetChildrenCore()
        {
            var list = base.GetChildrenCore();
            list.AddRange(GetChildPeers(Owner));
            return list;
        }

        private List<AutomationPeer> GetChildPeers(UIElement element)
        {
            var list = new List<AutomationPeer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as UIElement;
                if (child != null)
                {
                    AutomationPeer childPeer;
                    if (child is GroupItem)
                    {
                        childPeer = new GenericAutomationPeer(child);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        childPeer = UIElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(child);
                    }
                    if (childPeer != null)
                    {
                        list.Add(childPeer);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        list.AddRange(GetChildPeers(child));
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

}
```

I hope this helps anyone still searching for an answer!

Comment: This is not ideal but considering an effort of fixing AutomationPeer for grouped ItemsControls it is a very effective workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure about buttons, but `TextBlock` controls that are inside `DataTemplate`s do *not* get put into the UI Automation tree. Apparently this is an optimization to avoid 1000's of unneccessary textblocks.

You can work around it by SubClassing TextBlock. Here's mine:

```
public class AutomatableTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new AutomatableTextBlockAutomationPeer(this);
    }

    class AutomatableTextBlockAutomationPeer : TextBlockAutomationPeer
    {
        public AutomatableTextBlockAutomationPeer(TextBlock owner)
            : base(owner)
        { }

        protected override bool IsControlElementCore()
        { return true; }
    }
}
```

Note: UI Automation also doesn't expose various other controls like `Canvas`, `Panel`, you can get them to show up with a similar subclass.

In saying that, I'm not sure why the `Button` isn't appearing.... Hrmmm

Comment: The elements I need show up fine if grouping is disabled, so I don't think your answer helps I'm afraid. I used a button in the example for clarity as they always show up (except in this case!).

Answer (score 1):

What tools are you using to write the automated scripts? I would have thought there'd be an option to drill into WPF's logical/visual trees rather than relying on the Win32 tree (as surfaced by UISpy).

If you have a look at the same application using [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/), you'll see the full visual and logical trees.

Comment: I'm writing acceptance tests using MbUnit (but could be NUnit, xUnit.NET or whatever) and driving the application using the UI Automation framework. This decouples the tests from the implementation (to some extent) by dealing with UI items that the user can see and/or interact with rather than directly looking at the WPF trees. I've been doing this for about a year and this is the first case I've found that doesn't "just work," so I'm hoping to plug the gap rather than switch frameworks at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this in my application by using `TreeWalker.RawViewWalker` to manually navigate the tree after using `AutomationElement.FindFirst` to find the template. `FindFirst` seems to reliably exclude all the information you want when automating somebody else's application. `RawViewWalker` seems to work when the elements show up in "Inspect Objects", but not in UISpy or your application.

Comment: It worked! Interesting fact is that UISpy could not find child node on one computer but did find on another. Both computers have same specs and same software installed. Anyway, the trick with TreeWalker worked for both.

Comment: RawViewWalker does not seem to work for me on this grouping case. Calling RawViewWalker.GetFirstChild for the group item element still returns no child.